# Remove background color from buttons in Listbox (Windows Phone)

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a function connected to a buttonclick in i Listbox. It sets the background color of the selected button. The problem with this is that i only want one button at a time to act as selected. With this solution every button clicked gets the green background... how can i reset the buttons that are not selected to a black background?

```
private void SettingsChangeRegionButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button clickedButton = sender as Button;
    clickedButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
    RssStream choosenStream = GetRssStreamFromName(clickedButton.Content.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a button to be green while it is being pressed you should change the color which is used as the background in the `Pressed` state.

If you just want to highlight which is the currently selected item in the list(box) then you need to change the styling of the item in the `Selected` state.

Sorry, if you know this but to pre-empt your next question: You can change a template by selecting an item in the objects and timeline window in blend and selecting "Edit Template" (or "Edit Additional Templates" as appropriate).

Comment: Hmmm, I actually get the button the color i want, its removing the color from the buttons that are not selected thats the problem... Or am I missunderstanding your answer?

Comment: Ive been trying something like this to reset the rest of the buttons, but its not working.

            foreach (Button btn in SettingsListbox.Items)
                btn.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);